# Error on H2 Database when I converted my Jar file to Exe

Tags: java, h2, launch4j

Here's what I did:

1. I build my project and its dependence Libraries into one Jar file
2. I Convert it to exe Using VJtoExe and Launch4J

The Problem is, When I run the Exe file, the system connects to my H2 database but it can't find the tables in it.

This is how I connect to my Database

```
Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;IFEXISTS=TRUE;", "admin", "denrlb");
stat = conn.createStatement();
```

**Update:**

Now I use Server Mode, in NetBeans it works fine, the server start automatically, but when i compiled it and convert the .jar to .exe the server does not start automatically, to make it work, i need to open the h2 manually,

how can i make it open the server automatically?

Comment: And how do you initialize the database? Or if it is a file-based one are you sure that you connect to the right one?

Comment: See my Edit sir @GHajba

Comment: And how do you initialize your tables if the database is empty? Or do you know that your database has to contain the tables?

Comment: when i run it on .jar it perfectly works

Comment: but on .exe the tables are not found